# Integration by Parts in complex analysis

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

I am going through some of the basic commutation relations in Virasaro Algebra. To obtain the lie algebra for the generators of conformal transformation, I am having some difficulty in complex integration. The statement of my problem is the following: Can we have an identity of the following form analogous to integration by parts in real analysis?

$$\oint_{C} d\omega \,\, \partial_{\omega} \hat{T}(\omega) \,\, \omega^{m+n+2} = -(m+n+2) \oint_{C} d\omega \,\, \hat{T}(\omega) \,\, \omega^{m+n+1}$$

where $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: What is $C$? Is it a closed loop?

Comment: Yes, C is a closed loop around either a singular or non-singular point.

Comment: If there are no singularities the equation is true trivially as both sides are $0$ and the loop is closed. If there are singularities, whether or not you have a valid antiderivative in the first place I am not sure

Comment: For non-singular point around the closed loop, the identity is trivial. But, i don't understand when you comment on the part when there is singularity around the closed loop.

Comment: If there is singularity, the antiderivatives are not everywhere holomorphic, so I'm uncertain if you can treat the integral using antiderivatives (which is where ibp comes in). p.s: you should add more detail to your question - your own thoughts, why you think the identity should hold, what is $T$, etc.

Comment: Have you tried using the definition of line integral and the usual integration by parts to prove it? I think attempting this will help you answer your question. Actually, on second thought, I think it obviously will be true since the fundamental theorem of calculus still holds, and the product rule still holds.

Comment: @FShrike I have encountered a similar thing in Ginsparg lectures on CFT (arXiv:hep-th/9108028). In these lecture notes, they have shown that the commutator of mode operators of stress-energy tensor (T) is closed and have a particular form (see section 3.3 for reference). To obtain that form (equation 3.8a), they should have used the identity that I have posed here. But I am having difficulty in understanding why this must be true. Btw, thanks for your input.

Comment: Reading their paper, they do indeed seem to integrate by parts. They said something about “no power law singularities” so I gather that all the involved functions are holomorphic in that region: it is Morrera’s theorem (if I remember correctly) that all holomorphic functions on an open region have an antiderivative. Then we can integrate by parts (I think) since the fundamental theorem of calculus does actually apply now that the antiderivative is known to exist. They also say $[L_nL_m]=0$ for this reason (because antiderivatives evaluated around a *closed* loop of course have $F(z)-F(z)=0$)

Comment: But it is strange, as they only say $[L,\overline{L}]=0$ and not for the other cases. So I am not sure